# DialogFragment onClick listener doesn't work with ImageButton

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, onclicklistener, dialogfragment

I think I tried everything that was provided here. I have ImageButton in my activity and I can't set it to switch to another activity (Log.d shows that it's not even clicked).

Here's my Dialog:

```
    public class StarsActivity extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    Dialog dialog;
    Activity mActivity;

    ImageButton nextQuestion;

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_stars, null);

        setCancelable(true);
        return view;
    }

    /** The system calls this only when creating the layout in a dialog. */
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The only reason you might override this method when using onCreateView() is
        // to modify any dialog characteristics. For example, the dialog includes a
        // title by default, but your custom layout might not need it. So here you can
        // remove the dialog title, but you must call the superclass to get the Dialog.
        dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        //Setting transparency for dialog background
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        //No title for dialog
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_stars);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        nextQuestion = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.nextQuestion);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, nextQuestion.toString());
        nextQuestion.setOnClickListener(this);

        mActivity = getActivity();

        return dialog;
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.nextQuestion:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 2: ");
                mActivity = getActivity();
                Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, FinalActivity.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(i);
                this.dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my ImageButton xml:

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/nextQuestion"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_content_nextbutton_02"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

I hope there's a way to solve it.

Comment: I can not understand your problem can you please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is No need for you to have an instanse of Dialog in your StarsActivity which is already extending from Dialog fragment.
The below code does everything that you want

```
public class StarsActivity extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Activity mActivity;
    ImageButton nextQuestion;

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_stars, null);
        nextQuestion = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.nextQuestion);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, nextQuestion.toString());
        nextQuestion.setOnClickListener(this);
        setCancelable(true);
        return view;
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.nextQuestion:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 2: ");
                mActivity = getActivity();
                Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, FinalActivity.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(i);
                this.dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please consider renaming StarsActivity as StarsDialog or something else.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I need my dialog to have features as: have no title, transparent background, have parent's width and with onCreateView I can't get it to work.

Comment: I managed to get it working with keeping onCreateDialog() method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in your Oncreate method add this line :

```
nextQuestion.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: You cant reference layout ids on a `DialogFragment` in `onCreate`, the view of the fragment is set in `onCreateDialog` only then you can reference the ids.